# Constant weight for each part in a bool query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

Is it possible to get number of "shoulds" matched or return constant weight per each should matched. For example, if I have a bool query like this:

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    { "match": { "last_name": "Shcheklein" }}, 
                    { "match": { "first_name": "Bart" }}
                ]
         }
   }
```

I would like to get:

`score == 1` if one of the fields (`last_name`, `first_name`) matches (even in a fuzzy sense)
`score == 2` if both fields match

And is it possible to get a list of fields matched?

Answer (score 3):

you could probably use c[onstant score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) to achieve this and
use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-highlighting.html) to figure out the fields that matched.

Example :

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "disable_coord": true,
         "should": [
            {
               "constant_score": {
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "last_name": "Shcheklein"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "constant_score": {
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "first_name": "bart"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost": 1
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It appears `constant_score` doesn't allow wrapping any query anymore, did something change?